# PuTTY window does not allow me to copy/paste from/to Windows

Tags: windows, putty

My PuTTY window does not allow me to copy/paste from/to Windows?
I see other people do it, but in Windows -copy- and in PuTTY-window right-click does nothing

Answer (score 7):

you can enable this option in your putty configuration page(category > windows > selection)

```
Compromise(middle extends, Right pastes)
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

First enable

> Compromise(middle extends, Right pastes)

in your puTTy configuration page(category -> windows -> selection)
then copy text from windows as usual Ctrl + c. Then

> SHIFT + Ins

in puTTY should work!

Comment: The first part of your answer was already given by somebody else, four years ago, in much greater detail. Before posting an answer, you should read all the existing answers to see whether the information has already been covered. It’s OK to refer to a previous answer in order to build on it, but you must ***refer** to* the previous answer, giving credit to its author.  As to the second part of your answer: the OP wants a way to paste using the mouse. Why are you giving instructions to configure the way the mouse works, and then saying to use the keyboard to paste?

Comment: I hugely appreciate your answer (the second part). I have no problem with people showing something interesting and related. I don't know why people object to that.

Answer (score 0):

From past experience, PuTTY copy and pastes just by selecting the text you want to copy within the PuTTY window.

For example - Left click and hold and then drag over what you want to copy. Once you release left click, whatever was highlighted is automatically copied.

You can then paste this by right-clicking in the PuTTY window and it will paste your selection. Ctrl + C/V will not do anything.

For copying from Windows into PuTTY, you can copy the text you need to the normal way (Ctrl + C or Right Click and select Copy) and then inside your PuTTY window, just right click.

If this doesn't work, inside your PuTTY configuration menu, under Window -> Selection, you can check to see what your Mouse Controls are set to.

-Mike

Comment: Mike, based on his question, on the very last sentence of your answer is applicable. He specified he's pasting INTO Putty an external source, and that Right-Click isn't working to paste.

Comment: Understood - I was just laying the base on how Copy/Paste works in PuTTY and to make sure that he was, in-fact, copy/pasting the way PuTTY handles it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to copy from Putty window to host computer window (in Linux OS)
        (1) Select section in Putty window
        (2) Right click on mouse
        (3) Move the pointer to host computer window
        (4) (Push) Center wheel on mouse

I haven't tried in Windows OS.

Comment: Copy/paste generally works by default.  Apparently, the OP hadn't configured Putty.  The correct answer was given nearly 10 years ago: `Putty > Windows > Selection > Compromise=Enabled...`

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks for indication regarding OP configuration. I just add another way, which is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing a similar issue with pasting text in a file opened with emacs through PuTTY.

Unfortunately, pasting seems to be corrupting my files as they don't behave normally after using it : sending point to the end of the line ends up in the middle, deleting what seem to be empty spaces actually makes characters appear after I start deleting...

For instance, I'm trying to paste code to embed a tweet.

Do you have any idea about how to fix this ? I'm starting to look into emacs configuration but to no avail so far. I'm a very new user to linux and PuTTY.

Thanks !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).